# EMF Plus vs. PNG format vbs

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to check in a Word file, if EMF embedded images are stored in PNG format (inside the EMF). Does there exist any simple check? I know already the code from [exportpictures](http://www-pc.uni-regensburg.de/systemsw/office/vba/exportpictures.htm) but this code does not check the contents of the EMF file itself. I just need a check - no image saving required.

Comment: A really crude check would find the PNG binary marker inside the EMF binary. Otherwise I suspect you'll need to use the APIs for enumerating the EMF records, and only check the records that can contain PNGs.

Comment: I thought so as well, just doing a quick binary search..